# Работа в C с Python.h

Tags: python-3.x, c

По определённым причинам, мне потребаволось написать модуль для Python на C. Для начала, решил попробовать ctypes, но с по каким-то причинам мне не удавалось сделать так, чтобы код работал корректно.
Тогда, я решил попробовать Python.h. Для этого, я сделал файл setup.py, c
определенным кодом:

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name='<name>', version='1.0',\
      ext_modules=[Extension('<name>', ['<filename.c>'])])
```

После чего, запустил команду в cmd:
`python setup.py install`
Сначала, я получил ошибку, говорящая о том, что нет определённого .bat файла, но потом у меня получилось её решить. После повторной попытки запуска команды все прошло успешно. Но, когда я запускаю основной Python скрипт с использованием данной библиотеки, возникает ошибка: `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 не является приложением Win32.`.

Операционная система - Windows 10, версия 1803.

Версия Python - 3.7.

Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19019720

Comment: @вася у меня немного другая проблема. Там она решалась с помощью скачивания модулей с других мест или проверкой скачана ли версия библиотеки 64 битная или 32 битная, а так же скодится ли разрядность Python и библиотеки. У меня же что-то типа своей библиотеки поэтому я не смогу скачать её из "других мест", а проблема с разрядностью вряд-ли относится к моей

Comment: Почему вряд ли? У вас dll может быть не той же разрядности, что питон

Comment: Версия Python у меня 64 битная. Все инструменты, для компиляции в DLL тоже 64 битные. Каким образом могло получится что-то 32 битное? А даже если так, не могли бы вы мне подсказать, как это исправить?

Comment: Использовать одинаковые версии :)

Comment: Одинаковые версии чего?

Comment: Что может быть не той разрядности?

Comment: dll и интерпретатор, я же написал

Comment: хмм, и как вы думаете, как я буду это делать? Компиляция, как я понял, происходила в основном с помощью компилятора от Visual Sudio, который был 64 битный. Как вы думаете, как могло получится что-то не 64 битное? Версия Python тоже 64 битная

Comment: Я не знаю, как у вас происходила компиляция. Я просто предложил один из вариантов, с которым сталкивался сам. Если вы уверены, что проблема не в этом, то ищите другие решения

Comment: Если компилятор 64 битный, то это не значит, что артефакты сборки тоже 64 битные.

Comment: @user7860670 что вы предлагаете мне сделать?